# Failed to create a new partition on the selected unused space. [Error:0x8004240f]

Tags: windows-7

I got this error when trying to make a new partition:

> Failed to create a new partition on the selected unused space. [Error:0x8004240f]

Why, and what should I do to resolve it?

Comment: note this partition is 93 GB

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. This is a programming question and answer site, not a place for general computer support. The [FAQ](http://stackoverflow.com/faq) has more info about the types of questions that are proper for this site. I've voted to move your question to another of the StackExchange sites that's more fitting for it. Feel free to post your programming questions here in the future,and we'll be glad to try and help you get an answer. :-)

Comment: how many partitions do you already have?

Answer (score 1):

1. Insert Windows XP bootable disk and create just 3 partitions (NOTE-not more than 3.)
2. Next, insert Windows 7 CD and in the CMD type "list disk". All the disks will be listed.
3. Then type "select disk 0" the disk will be selected.
4. Now type "clean".
5. After the clean ends successfully type - "active" then type "end" and press <kbd>Enter</kbd>.

Now you can finish the installation successfully.

Answer (score 0):

As per this document, http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_7-windows_install/error-0x8004240f-failed-to-create-a-new-partition/03270f3f-116e-4d1d-8f27-17ff1108460d

The issue seems to appear when you're attempting to create more than 4 partitions. The document illustrates how to erase/recreate the partitions so take a look if you accept that.